# 2022 cs50 finince - why does my function return error to confirm password even when i do confirm the password?

Tags: python, flask, cs50, finance

When i try to register it always outputs the error/apology "must confirm password".Which should only show if I don't confirm my password which I do.
This is the code for apology function:

```
def apology(message, code=400):
    """Render message as an apology to user."""
    def escape(s):
        """
        Escape special characters.

        https://github.com/jacebrowning/memegen#special-characters
        """
        for old, new in [("-", "--"), (" ", "-"), ("_", "__"), ("?", "~q"),
                         ("%", "~p"), ("#", "~h"), ("/", "~s"), ("\"", "''")]:
            s = s.replace(old, new)
        return s
    return render_template("apology.html", top=code, bottom=escape(message)), code
```

This is my code for register.function:

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register user"""

    #user reaches route via POST
    if request.method == "POST":
        # check for possible errors

        # must provide username
        username =request.form.get("username")
        password =request.form.get("password")
        confirmation =request.form.get("confiramtion")

        if not username:
            return apology("must provide username", 400)
        #must provide password
        elif not password :
            return apology("must provide password", 400)
        #must confirm password
        elif not confirmation:
           return apology("must confirm password",400)

        #check if passwords match
        if passwowrd !=  confirmation:
            return apology("password doesen't match",400)

request.form.get("username"))
        #check if username taken
        #insert new user into users table
        hash = generate_password_hash(password)
        try:
            db.execute("INSERT INTO users(username,hash ) VALUES(?,?)",username,hash)
            return redirect("/")
        except:

            return apology("username is already taken", 400)

    else :
            return render_template("register.html")
```

This is my register.html template:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Register
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="/register" method="post">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" id="password" name="confirmation" placeholder="confirm password" type="password">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I don't understand why it doesen't work does anybody have a tip?
I changed my if statements and changing the placement of the code and changed the way I wrote it but I can't find the error.I looked at suggestions of others who hade problems with register function nothing helped.
I am a begginer so I don't have any ideas how to fix it.Please help!

Comment: Fix your typo here: `request.form.get("confiramtion")`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see what the typo is

Comment: You wrote `confiramtion` instead of `confirmation`..

Comment: Thank you soo much. Now it works.I'm very happy.<3